# Hi,the submit in this project is not working,how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

When I click submit in the add tasks page, I get no response. The submit button is supposed to add tasks to the list in the tasks page. It does not show any errors and I'm not sure if its code is even running.

views.py:

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.

class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="New Task")

# Add a new task:
def index(request):

    # Check if there already exists a "tasks" key in our session

    if "tasks" not in request.session:

    # If not, create a new list
        request.session["tasks"] = []

    return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {
        "tasks": request.session["tasks"]
    })

    def add(request):
    # Check if method is POST
        if request.method == "POST":

        # Take in the data the user submitted and save it as form
            form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)

        # Check if form data is valid (server-side)
            if form.is_valid():

            # Isolate the task from the 'cleaned' version of form data
                task = form.cleaned_data["task"]

            # Add the new task to our list of tasks
                request.session["tasks"] += [task]

            # Redirect user to list of tasks
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tasks:index"))

        else:

            # If the form is invalid, re-render the page with existing information.
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {
                "form": form
            })

    return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {
        "form": NewTaskForm()
    })
```

---

add.html template:

---

```
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Add Task:</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'tasks:add' %}" method="post"></form>
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:index' %}">View Tasks</a>
{% endblock %}
```

---

index.html:

```
***
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Tasks:</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <li>{{ task }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No tasks</li>
        {% endfor %}
       </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">Add a New Task</a>
{% endblock %}
***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form element is closed out prematurely, so clicking the input probably doesn't do anything at all. If it somehow does, because you still have a closing `</form>` tag then it doesn't know where to send the `POST` to.

```html
<form action="{% url 'tasks:add' %}" method="post"></form> <-- This
```